# Difference between integration of pdf in joint probability and conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

What is the difference in 
$\Pr(X>aY+b, Y>c)$ and $\Pr(X>aY+b|Y>c)$ in terms of the integration of the their pdf.
X and Y are indpendent RV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ P(X>aY + b, Y>c) =  \int_{c}^\infty\int_{ay+b}^{\infty} dF_X(x) dF_Y(y)$$ 
where $dF_X(x)= f_X(x) dx$ and $dF_Y(y)= f_Y(y) dy$ if both variables are abs. continuous. 
$$ P(X>aY+b | Y>c) = \frac{P(X>aY+b , Y>c)}{P(Y>c)} $$
where  $P(Y>c) = \int_c^\infty dF_Y(y)$. If X and Y are independent then $f_{X|Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)$.

Comment: Can X and Y be still independent if we take $X > aY + b$?

Comment: Well if you take $Z=X-aY$ as a new variable, then $Z$ is not independent of $Y$